# How do we find pure ruby programming language questions?

Tags: support, questions, search

I am looking for pure ruby programming language questions.

I started with the tag ruby, but found many rails specific questions on rails that are incorrectly tagged ruby (usually alongside one or more rails tags).

I then tried `[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails*]` - to eliminate rails questions tagged ruby. However, the results still show questions specific to ruby-related technologies like cucumber, rspec, etc. that are also tagged ruby. I could extend it with exclusions for each technology, but is that the best way possible?

I cannot turn it into a text search for exclusion (for example, `[ruby] -rails` will exclude ruby language questions that happen to use a rails example.

How can I best find pure ruby programming language questions, excluding all other ruby-related technology specific questions?

Comment: I posted both this question and the one that @Makoto marked duplicate - This question is about: I want to find  only pure ruby programming questions. The first question was one aspect of it which excluded specific tags, and I figured out how to do that - but there are still many redundant answers which involve cucumber, etc. - I am trying to understand the best way to find only pure ruby language questions.

Comment: If you find incorrectly tagged questions, please edit them.

Comment: it's not often that you find good questions with a single tag, that's usually a sign of low quality

Comment: here's a data explorer query that you can use to find questions: [Newest Unanswered Questions with a single tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211290)